# recapping my bottles? Will it ruin the outcome of my beer?

Tags: beer, techniques, bottling, over-carbonation

I bottled my first batch of homebrew and didnt fill the bottles all the way. So the next day I opened the bottles and poured some more beer into them and recapped them.. I this going to mess up the whole entire batch or am I ok? Now there is about a 1-2 in of air space in the bottles. Just didnt have enough beer in the bottles and didnt want them to explode all over.. Just wanting to know if it will still carbonate after doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you were careful about sanitization, the batch should be fine, 1-2 inches of head space is about right.  For future reference (if you didn't already know) when you are using a bottle filler, just fill the bottle to the top and when you remove the filler you should have the right amount of head space.