# will i end up with flat beer?

Tags: beer, carbonation, recapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [recapping my bottles? Will it ruin the outcome of my beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/recapping-my-bottles-will-it-ruin-the-outcome-of-my-beer)

I was wondering if my beer will end up flat no carbonation because i ended up recapping the whole batch. I recapped the batch after i didnt have enough in the bottles. So i poured more in two days after bottling to top them off so i wouldnt have any explode on me.. The main thing that im worried about is that they will not carbonate now?

Comment: Not meaning to be rude, but is this not the same question you already asked, ["Recapping my bottles..."](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/recapping-my-bottles-will-it-ruin-the-outcome-of-my-beer)?

Comment: voted to close.  if the answer wasn't thorough enough the first time around, please make a comment in that thread, and someone will inevitably elaborate on the answer.  reasking the question isn't going to carbonate your beer.